# Locate dataframe rows where values are outside bounds specified for each column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with *k* columns and *n* rows, *k* ~= 10, *n* ~= 1000. I have a (2, *k*) array representing bounds on values for each column, e.g.:

```
# For 5 columns
bounds = ([0.1, 1, 0.1, 5, 10], 
          [10, 1000, 1, 1000, 50])

# Example df
     a    b    c    d    e
0    5    3    0.3  17   12
1    12   50   0.5  2    31
2    9    982  0.2  321  21
3    1    3    1.2  92   48

# Expected output with bounds given above
     a    b    c    d    e
0    5    3    0.3  17   12
2    9    982  0.2  321  21
```

Crucially, the bounds on each column are different.

I would like to identify and exclude **all** rows of the dataframe where **any** column value falls outside the bounds for that respective column, preferably using array operations rather than iterating over the dataframe. The best I can think of so far involves iterating over the columns (which isn't too bad but still seems less than ideal):

```
for i in len(df.columns):
    df = df.query('(bounds[0][i] < df.columns[i]) & (df.columns[i] < bounds[1][i])')
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or alternatively, to select only the rows where all column values are within the respective bounds?

Comment: Why not build your query string up and then execute it at once? Could be more efficient.

Comment: That's true, would definitely be more efficient to only query the dataframe once I think. But am still wondering if there are any built-in functions to do this more elegantly?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data with k=3 and n=5 (or 10) with bounds and indicate the expected result for that? Thank you.

Comment: [pd.Series.between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) might be a bit more elegant, but you'd still need to loop through all bounds, and multiply the resulting series together to get an indexer.

Comment: @cs95 added an example!

Answer (score 2):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with `pandas.Series.between`:

```
bounds = dict(zip(df.columns, zip(*bounds)))

new_df = df[~df.apply(lambda x: ~x.between(*bounds[x.name])).any(1)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   a    b    c    d   e
0  5    3  0.3   17  12
2  9  982  0.2  321  21
```